# Convert special character '&' , '>' and '<' to their respective character reference for XML

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I need to replace only these 3 symbol for my XML:

1. & to `&amp;`
2. < to `&lt;`
3. > to `&gt;`

I used [htmlspecialchars](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp) but it will replace single and double quotes too.

Comment: Well, the quotes are special in XML. Why *wouldn't* you want to convert them?!

Comment: Actually I have two application in UI side, one is GWT and another one is php. GWT sends the map to our services(Java based) and I am creating the XML just as that of map. And our services can bear the quotes but when I pass &, it gives an exception:

"The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

Comment: So... converting them wouldn't be a problem...?

Comment: Not sure about others, but these three are arising issue.

Comment: I mean; converting *all of them* wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: All means ?, >, < , ' ,"      ??? or you are saying something else?

Comment: I'm saying, if you *do* encode all special characters (by the definition of `htmlspecialchars()`), is it an actual problem? Whoever's reading the XML should still get it right.

Comment: @Biffen I got the exact issue, you were right I can encode all special character. The problem was the service [Elastic Server] while reading this XML is not able to parse "AND" ,"OR" and "NOT",it takes it logically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [htmlspecialchars](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp) documentation. You can use flags to ignore quotes (you might be interested in the ENT_NOQUOTES flag).

Here's an example from the same article :

```
<?php
$str = "Jane & 'Tarzan'";
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT); // Will only convert double quotes
echo "<br>";
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES); // Converts double and single quotes
echo "<br>";
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES); // Does not convert any quotes
?>
```